# Nservicebus and security apects

Tags: nservicebus

NserviceBus ESB supports any/all of the following security aspects?
 •ACEGI
 •JAAS
 •PGP

As far as we analyzed there does not seem to any support for these security aspects in NserviceBus ESB.Please clarify.

Note:Mule seems to support all of these.So need the same information about NserviceBus.

Comment: not relevant to the software in question

Answer (score 1):

NServiceBus has encryption facilities that are pluggable, with a default implementation that uses the Rijndael algorithm, the defacto implementation of AES.

You also have the ability to define authentication at different stages of its pipeline.